# Pointer arithmetic C and casting

Tags: c, pointers

I've seen a very strange code snippet and i am not quite sure if i understood it right:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(char *argc, char **argv)
{
   char a[50];
   *(char *) (a + 2) = 'b'; // <== THE LINE WHICH CONFUSES ME

   printf("value: %c\n", a[2]);
   return 1;
}
```

Is it right that we go 2 buckets further cast the 'b' into a pointer to the b and then dereference it?

Comment: You already have some good answers. Just remember that with the C language you can enjoy the advantages of safe coding and pointer arithmetic - just choose which one you want :)

Comment: The `argc` argument really should be `int`. There are computers out there where `int` and `char*` have different representations rendering your program behaviour very undefined. Also you don't use `argc` or `argv` for anything, so the simplest thing to do is to not declare them at all: `int main(void) { /* ... */}`. And one more also is that the return value of 1 can be interpreted differently by different Operating Systems. Prefer `return 0;` or `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` or `return EXIT_FAILURE;`.

Answer (score 6):

That's exactly equivalent of

```
*(a + 2) = 'b';
```

The cast is unnecessary.

All it does is add two to the array-which-decays-to-a-pointer `a`, dereference the resulting pointer, and assign the character `'b'` to that memory location.

When `a` is a pointer, the code `a[x]` is exactly equivalent of `*(a + x)`. So in your case, `*(a + 2) = 'b'` is exactly the same as `a[2] = 'b'`.

Answer (score 3):

`*(char *) (a + 2)`

is equivalent to

`a[2]`

By definition, `a[2]` is `*(a + 2)`. The value of `a + 2` is already of type `char *` so a cast of `a + 2` to `char *`, as is `(char *) (a + 2)`, is a no operation.

Comment: Although casts between pointer types in C (and C-style casts between pointer types in C++?) are always no-ops :)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>  *(char *) (a + 2) = 'b'; // <== THE LINE WHICH CONFUSES ME
> ```

This line literally means the very same as

```
a[2] = 'b'
```

The first cast `(char*)` is redundant, since a is already of type `char`. And indexing in fact translates to addition and dereferenciation, i.e.

```
a[n] === *(a + n)
```

A little known fact about C: You could write as well

```
n[a]
```

and get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't casting the `'b'`.

You cast `(a+2)` to `char*` (Which does nothing, since it's already `char*`), deference it, and put there `'b'`.

And yes, it is right that we go 2 buckets further.

Answer (score 1):

No, you treat `a` as a pointer, increment it by two, then cast it to `(char*)` (useless cast, it already is `char*`), dereference it and then store `'b'` into that.

It is exactly the same as this:

```
a[2] = 'b';
```